# SSRS 2008 R2 - Printing in portrait rather than landscape from report server link

Tags: sql, report, reporting-services

Having an issue with one of my SSRS reports where if I print direct from the server it prints in portrait and thus cuts off the left hand side of the report, basically it seems to print off the right side OK and prints as far left as possible within the page. It is not as if the rest of the report gets printed on a seperate page thats it.

If I export to PDF and print it works fine, it seems to do only do this when printing from the report server.

Interactive Size and page size are both Width 29.7cm Height 21cm.

Any advice?

Cheers

Comment: Does it happen on all reports?  Have you tried other printers?  And you mean you are printing through IE using the activeX print button built into SSRS?

Answer (score 2):

In report designer, ensure that *Report -> Report Properties -> Paper size -> Orientation* is set to Landscape.

Additionally, ensure that the width of the report's *Body* plus the width of the *Left* & *Right Margin* (on the same *Report Properties* dialog above) do not exceed the *Paper size Width* and *Height*.

Finally, again in the designer click the *Preview* tab and click *Print Layout* to ensure the print preview is rendering the report in landscape.

Comment: Was set to landscape. Made sure the body including the margins were in size and that was fine (good tip though) and the print preview also rendered it properly in landscape. Bizarre, I reckon its a printer issue but dont have access to another printer at the moment so will put it on hold in the time being and print via pdf if needed but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a link in a report, this is a known bug, where the properties don't propagate from the parent report to the linked report.

[Click here for the link](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/225025/linked-report-makes-a-landscape-report-appear-portrait-in-print-preview#details)